# Exectue function every one hour in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I wanted to execute a program every once hour. I can use time.sleep function to delay the interval but, if the program executed let's say at 16:30 then the function will only execute at 17:30. But I need to execute the function at 17:00, 18:00 and so on.

```
import datetime

def onehour(value):
   print "%d Hours" % value

now = datetime.datetime.now()
oncehour(now.hour)
```

Comment: Do you need to do this within your script, or could you e.g. use a cronjob to launch a script hourly?

Comment: Python will be better. I've tried the same cronjob, which was super easy. I may using the same program in Windows too.

Comment: Then you should use an appropriate scheduler on Windows - this will be much easier than having Python burning cycles "waiting" for the top of the next hour.

Comment: Okay. Any way with python ?

Comment: Well you could have a `while` loop which calls your function when the time is on or just after a round hour, that wouldn't be terribly *difficult* to write, but it's better to rely on the OS for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sleep first, if current time is 12:23, then you need to sleep 60-23 = 37 minutes and then run your code every hour.
Here you can write like this:

```
import time
import datetime

time.sleep(60 * (60 - datetime.datetime.now().minute))
while True:
    do_smth()
    sleep(60 * 60)
```

Comment: Also you should measure time taken to execute do_smth function and subtract that time from sleep(60*60)

Answer (score 1):

What about [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs ? You can write your code inside a Python file then call it from command line inside your crontab:

```
0 * * * * python script.py
```

Comment: Windows doesn't support "cron". So only Python can do good. :)

Comment: So you want to run a Python script infinitely ? I would look for a task scheduling in Windows.